TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable while fetching information for rejected reason from jira
for issue in issues:
    fields = issue['fields']
    results.append({
        'key': issue['key'],
        'summary': fields['summary'],
        'description': fields['description'],
        'fix_details': get_custom_field_value(fields, 'customfield_25600'),  # Replace with actual custom field ID
        'url': f"{JIRA_SERVER}/browse/{issue['key']}",
        'status' : fields['status']['name'],
        'rejected_reason': fields['customfield_19822']['value']
    })

I have a piece of python code but when I try to execute this, it failed in this block for last row
'rejected_reason': fields['customfield_19822']['value'] as there are multiple records for which, this field value is not populated or is None. This code works fine for those records where some valid value for this field is present.
File "c:\projects\LL\Jira_LL\jira_LL.py", line 84, in query
    'rejected_reason': fields['customfield_19822']['value']
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

I have tried to put if else
 'rejected_reason': fields['customfield_19822']['value']
             if rejected_reason is not None: 
                   rejected_reason={rejected_reason}
             else
                   rejected_reason=NULL

but this is failing with
     if rejected_reason is not None:
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


It looks like you were trying to use the ternary expression syntax x if condition else y.  So in your case it would be 'rejected_reason': fields['customfield_19822']['value'] if fields['customfield_19822'] is not None else "something"

As you discovered you cannot put a full if/else block inside of a dictionary block. You can use a conditional expression (sometimes referred to as a ternary expression).
So while this kind of looks like what you want, it doesn't work:
d = {
    if data['x'] is None:
        'field': 'empty'
    else:
        'field': data['x']['y']
}

Use the conditional expression instead:
d = {
    'field': data['x']['y'] if data['x'] is not None else 'empty'
}

# or with more error checking for this specific case:
d = {
    'field': data['x']['y'] if 'x' in data and data['x'] is not None else 'empty'
}


